# Geração de boleto em .NET

Tags: c#, .net, boleto

Até hoje muitas vezes imaginei situações nas quais um sistema poderia precisar gerar boletos, embora até o momento nunca tenha desenvolvido nada assim, e então resolvi pesquisar como fazer isso em .NET. Pesquisei um pouco e tudo que encontrei foi uma biblioteca chamada Boleto.NET.

Analisei um pouco essa biblioteca mas estou procurando alternativas. Primeiro porque estou trabalhando com ASP.NET 5 e ainda não consegui fazer essa biblioteca funcionar nem com a Full CLR (nesse ponto acho que é algum erro menor que eu cometi). Em segundo lugar porque olhando na página do GitHub não entendi muito bem a proposta. Parece que tem um site misturado com a biblioteca e uma outra aplicação MVC também, enfim, não entendi muito bem se trata-se só de uma biblioteca ou uma aplicação construída para gerar boletos.

Dessa forma continuei pesquisando sobre o assunto mas não encontrei muita coisa e resolvi perguntar aqui.

- Como posso gerar boletos em .NET de uma forma razoavelmente simples dentro da aplicação que estou desenvolvendo?
- Se eu nao quiser usar essa biblioteca que encontrei só fazendo manualmente? E nesse caso como isso é feito em .NET?

Comment: Acho que a pergunta é muito ampla. Esta biblioteca é meia-boca mesmo, mas é o que tem pronto. Pode pegar a ideia ali, ou olhar outras implementações em linguagens diferentes e tentar portar. Ainda que a maioria que tem disponível é bem meia-boca também. Não resolvem bem certas questões e adotam complicações desnecessárias para a maioria.

Comment: Não acho simples esse problema. A Boleto.NET é bem mal estruturada e precisaria de algum retrabalho pra ficar boa. Como o ASP.NET 5 ainda não é estável, não sei se vale a pena ir para isso agora.

Comment: Precisa mesmo disso implementado dentro da aplicação? Estudou a possibilidade de usar um serviço de geração, gerenciamento e notificação de boletos como o cobregratis.com.br?

Comment: Se você tiver um servidor sql server com report service, acredito que seja a melhor alternativa usar o serviço de relatório. Cria o boleto lá no SRSS e faz a chamada do boleto pelo .net passando os parâmetros.

Answer (score 6):

Quase um ano depois da sua pergunta, posso afirmar que a `Boleto.Net` evoluiu muito.

O boleto sem registro da forma como o conhecemos vai deixar de existir no final de 2016. Se sua empresa trabalha com esta modalidade, é bom estar a par do que está acontecendo e se preparar para a mudança. Ou seja, agora todos os boletos vão ser com registro e as empresas terão que gerar um arquivo de remessa e enviá-lo para o banco.

A `Boleto.Net` já está sendo adequada para essa mudança e gera o arquivo de remessa.

Eu estou atualmente trabalhando com ela. Inclusive os erros que encontrei, reportei aos contribuintes do projeto. Como o projeto é *open source*, você também pode fazer a alteração e mandar para eles.

O ponto negativo dela é não ter documentação. Eu, por exemplo, trabalho com ela e a documentação do banco juntas para poder entender os campos.

O ponto positivo é que está evoluindo e atualmente já possui as seguintes funcionalidades:

- Emissão e Impressão de Boletos Bancários
- Geração de Arquivo de Remessa dos layouts

  - CNAB 240
  - CNAB 400
- Leitura do Arquivo de Retorno dos layouts

  - CNAB240
  - CNAB400
  - CBR643

Você pode conferir a lista dos bancos [implementados](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/wiki/Bancos-Implementados) e dos [homologados](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet/wiki/Bancos-Homologados) e outras informações no [github](https://github.com/BoletoNet/boletonet).

Answer (score 1):

Como foi dito nos comentários, não há uma forma simples de se fazer isso.

Se você tem controle total do servidor, para instalar um software nele eu te indico fazer uma integração com o software ACBrMonitorPlus. Com esse software você pode enviar comandos via TCP-IP utilizando a classe Socket(System.Net.Sockets).

Você pode enviar alguns comandos como de gerar o boleto em PDF e entregar o PDF no Browser e tem outros comandos.Na pasta de instalação vem um arquivo . chm com os comandos disponíveis.

Você pode baixar gratuitamente.

Não é uma das alternativas mais simples, porém esse projeto tem muita colaboração da comunidade, e eu o uso para emissão de NFe, além de geração de PDF para o DANFe da nota fiscal, e funciona bem essa integração.

Seria mais ou menos assim

```
  IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"); //IP local(do servidor)
  IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, intPorta);
  Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
  socket.Connect(remoteEP);  
  byte[] bytes = new byte[2097152];
  byte[] msg = Encoding.GetEncoding(strEncoding).GetBytes("BOLETO.GerarPDF" + Environment.NewLine + "." + Environment.NewLine);
  int bytesSent = socket.Send(msg);
  int bytesRec = socket.Receive(bytes);
  string strMensagemRetorno = Encoding.GetEncoding(strEncoding).GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.sockets(v=vs.110).aspx
http://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/forum/54-acbrmonitor-plus/
http://www.projetoacbr.com.br/forum/files/file/372-acbrmonitorplus/